# Windows CIFS mount error "Function not implemented" or error -11 or -5

Tags: linux, mount, samba, cifs

I'm trying to mount a shared drive hosted on a Windows Server 2016 on Linux. The following command works without an error:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o credentials=*,vers=2.1,iocharset=utf8 //IP/drive shared_folder
```

However, when I try and cd to the directory I get the following error:

```
cd: cannot access shared_folder: Function not implemented
```

I have enabled CIFS debugging via `echo 7 > /proc/fs/cifs/cifsFYI` and can see this in the syslog (/var/log/messages):

```
kernel: [11393.577726] CIFS VFS: validate protocol negotiate failed: -11
kernel: [11393.589022] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -5
```

and this in dmesg log:

```
[ 5189.504559] CIFS VFS: validate protocol negotiate failed: -11
[ 5189.508793] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -5
[ 5441.124849] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -112
[ 5459.130519] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -112
[ 6294.098404] CIFS VFS: Unknown vers= option specified: 2
[ 6393.036888] CIFS VFS: Unknown vers= option specified: 4.0
[ 6398.978615] CIFS VFS: Unknown vers= option specified: 3.1
[ 6403.339841] CIFS VFS: validate protocol negotiate failed: -11
[ 6403.342874] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -5
[11393.577726] CIFS VFS: validate protocol negotiate failed: -11
[11393.589022] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -5
```

I am running a `Amazon Linux AMI release 2017.09` but I have also tried with a Ubuntu instance and got similar messages.

Any ideas? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused. Who is sharing the share: Windows or Samba? `cifs-utils` and `samba` are different packages; `cifs-utils` (which includes `mount.cifs`) is just a wrapper around the kernel support for CIFS filesystems. Samba doesn't have anything to do with mounting CIFS shares.

Comment: @AlexP Sorry, I am being sloppy with terminology. I am trying to mount a Windows shared drive using CIFS. I have edited above to make clearer. Does it now make sense?

Comment: Have you tried with  `vers=3.0` or `vers=2.0` and no `vers=`? And what does `credentials=*` mean?

Comment: @AlexP Yes I have tried different versions. vers 3 or 2 doesn't work on Amazon AMI while on Ubuntu vers 3 does work and gives same errors. credentials give the location to the credential file which contains the username, password and domain.

Comment: Did you specify a location to mount to in your mount command?

Comment: @RamanSailopal Yes "shared_folder". Its the last statement in the mount command

Comment: According to [this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2376455) on Ubuntu Forums you may want to drop the `vers=` and add `sec=ntlmsspi`...

Comment: @AlexP if I drop `vers` and add `sec=ntlmsspi` I get this error when mounting `mount error(112): Host is down`. If I keep the `vers` I get the same errors as above

Comment: Same dropping `vers` results in `Host is down`. The folders look like a shortcut (maybe created with mklink)

Answer (score 5):

I got the `Function not implemented` error when connecting to a server using SMB3.11 with DFS from CentOS7.  Check your kernel version (`uname -a`).  DFS support was added to the kernel in version 4.11.  See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/929331/486126) for more information.